Terminology for matrix multiplication being "preserved" after a linear map
I have a linear map $\mathcal{O}: \mathcal{H}_A\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_B$ from one Hilbert space to another. Let its action on a state $\rho$ be described as below
$$\rho \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(\rho)$$
It turns out that for any matrices $P, Q\in\mathcal{H}_A$, there exist $P', Q'\in\mathcal{H}_B$ such that
$$\mathcal{O}(P\rho Q) = P'\mathcal{O}(\rho) Q'.$$
What is the terminology to describe $\mathcal{O}$ when such a $P', Q'$ can always be explicitly written down for any $P, Q$?
